# <Booking::Participant::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f43c7564390>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Booking. rb

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

has_many :booking_participants, 
class_name: "Booking::Participant",     
foreign_key: "booking_id",      
dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :booking
```

In class file

```
def send_user_report(report)
        @report = report
        @user = report.user
        @program = report.program
        @enterprise = @program&.enterprise

        @booking = Booking.find_by(id: report.details["booking_id"])
```

HTML

```
<p class="label">Issue</p>
        <p class="content-a"><%= @booking.booking_participants%></p>
```

I am new to this platform and trying to get booking participants but show the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error. `@booking.booking_participants` returns a collection (an [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) instance). You should iterate over the collection and display the information you need.

```
<% @booking.booking_participants.each do |participant| %>
  <%= participant.method %>
<% end %>
```

Replace `method` with the methods that exist on the `Booking::Participant` model.

Note that I'm not using `<%=` on the collection since adding `=` will interpolate the collection as well.

Comment: I have added `<% @booking.booking_participants.each do |participant| %>
        <p class="content-a"><%=  @booking.booking_participants%></p>   
        <% end %>`
but still same issue

Comment: @ToufiqurRahman Use the variable `participant` in the loop to display the information related to the booking participant. Just updated my answer to give you an example.